# WebAPI 2: new http code needed for inactive accout login process failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Im creating a WEBAPI-2-based system with users, which are inactive after registration and they need to be activated before login to system. Im wonderig how to implement ACTIVATION process properly using good/proper pattern. My questions are the following:

**What HTTP code should be returned?**
I was planing to add new one like 420, but I dont know if I can use it. It's not belonging to enumaration HttpStatusCode?  Or should be used the existing HTTP error code, which one?

**Can new HTTP error code be added to HttpStatusCode enumeration, probably not?:)**

**What class should be used to return a result?** 
I want to return Activation Failure HTTP code (header) + id of user (body) ?

UPDATE1:
**HttpStatusCode.Conflict - can this http-errorcode be used when user fails to login to unactivated account?**

Answer (score 0):

Why not return 200, and add msg at content.